# Select Data From 3 Different Tables Group By and Limit upto 3

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 tables  named as Referrals, Providers, Suppliers.

Suppliers table

```
| id | name 
| 1  | Supplier A
| 2  | Supplier B
| 3  | Supplier C
| 4  | Supplier D
```

Providers table

```
| id | name 
| 1  | Provider A
| 2  | Provider B
| 3  | Provider C
| 4  | Provider D
```

Referrals table

```
| id | client_name | provider_id | supplier_id  | created_at
| 1  | Client A    | 1           | 1            | 2021-01-20
| 2  | Client B    | 1           | 1            | 2021-01-21
| 1  | Client C    | 2           | 1            | 2021-01-22
| 1  | Client A    | 2           | 2            | 2021-01-23
| 1  | Client A    | 3           | 2            | 2021-01-24
| 1  | Client A    | 1           | 3            | 2021-01-24
| 1  | Client A    | 4           | 3            | 2021-01-25
| 1  | Client A    | 4           | 4            | 2021-01-26
| 1  | Client A    | 1           | 1            | 2021-01-20
```

I want to count the number of referrals by each provider by supplier (top 3) in a month this format below:

Result format should be:

```
| id | referral_count | provider_id | supplier_id  | created_at
| 1  | 3         | 1           | 1            | January
| 2  | 2         | 1           | 1            | January
| 1  | 1         | 2           | 1            | January
| 1  | 2         | 2           | 2            | January
| 1  | 3         | 3           | 2            | January
| 1  | 1         | 1           | 2            | January
| 1  | 2         | 4           | 3            | January
| 1  | 3         | 4           | 3            | January
| 1  | 4         | 1           | 3            | January
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it should be a left join and an inner join?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you simply want a `count()` as a window function:

```
select r.*,
       count(*) over (partition by provider_id, supplier_id, year(created_at), month(created_at)) as referral_count
from referrals r;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(*)` window function to achieve that if your mysql version is 8 or higher:

```
select 
    id,
    (count(client_name) over (partition by provider_id, supplier_id, year(created_at), monthname(created_at))) referral_count, 
    provider_id, supplier_id, monthname(created_at) created_at
from Referrals;
```

If you are using older version of MySQL then you can use below option with subquery:

```
select id ,
(select count(*) from Referrals rf where rf.provider_id=r.Provider_id and rf.supplier_id=r.supplier_id
 group by provider_id , supplier_id  ,year(created_at),monthname(created_at)) referral_count,provider_id , supplier_id  ,monthname( created_at) created_at
from Referrals r;
```

**Output:**

| id | provider_id | supplier_id | referral_count | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | January |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | January |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | January |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | January |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | January |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | January |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 | January |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | January |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | January |

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: @Strawberry would you please guide me to find a better way publish output. So that I can avoid being downvotted.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. Could you please suggest me how can I create this kind of table from excel?

Comment: What's Excel got to do with it?

Comment: I copied the table from db-fiddler as markdown but when I am copying directly from sql server or excel file how can I create this table easily. Sorry to bother you. But in Stackoverflow I am newbie.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know.

Comment: I'ts ok. Thanks agian.